# Error building pkg-config-0.28 on OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, build-dependencies

I'm new to Mac and trying to build pkg-config-0.28 on OS X 10.8. I was able to configure successfully using:

```
./configure CC="gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64" CXX="g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64" CPP="gcc -E" CXXCPP="g++ -E" --with-internal-glib
```

I tried the "--with-internal-glib" after getting an error saying glib not found.

But now I'm getting the following error when I entered:

```
$ make -j8
```

Error message:

```
> CC       gvarianttype.lo
  CC       gversion.lo
  CC       gwakeup.lo
  CC       gprintf.lo
  CC       glib-unix.lo
  CC       gthread-posix.lo
  CC       giounix.lo
gutils.c: In function 'find_folder':
gutils.c:1423: warning: 'FSFindFolder' is deprecated (declared at /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Folders.h:290)
  CC       gspawn.lo
echo   > glib-public-headers.txt.tmp && mv glib-public-headers.txt.tmp glib-public-headers.txt
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/wn/zc31626x5mz7w57dq6cf8f7w0000gn/T//cczwFoWN.out
make[6]: *** [gvariant.lo] Error 
make[6]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Before that, I installed pkg-config-0.26 from a .pkg file but the problem is, it shows install successful but when I enter "pkg-config" in the terminal it says command not found. For this reason I thought of building from the latest release.

I really need this for building/compiling an opencv project. Now how I can get pkg-config to work? Please help.

Comment: No one!!! Please guys come on I really need this. At least tell me how I can get the pkg-config-0.26 running that I installed from the .pkg. I can see the *.pc files in "/usr/lib/pkgconfig" but when I type "pkg-config" in terminal it says command not found.